# Having text aligned differently inside a table

Tags: html, alignment

Note that I'm sorta new to HTML stuff in general, sorry if this is obvious

https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/136618113/nationalseries/driver.html

I'm trying to have Rank, Wins, etc on the left and the numbers on the right. Is there any easy way to do this?

Comment: i suggest you use http://jsfiddle.net/ to provide a sample for people to fiddle with

Comment: You should include the relevant code in the question itself. You should also validate your HTML code.

Comment: You can use a nested table for this.......

Comment: I couldn't figure out how to add code without it actually embedding itself into the post, sorry.

Here's the jsfiddle page: http://jsfiddle.net/x9Hz9/1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give to the table lines and cells to split the content. The images have to fill both cells so you can use colspan 2. Then on the cells which need to be aligned differently you can add some styling:

```
<tbody>
<tr valign="top">
<td width="200" colspan="2">
<img src="drivers/headers/test1.png">
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td  colspan="2">
<img src="drivers/cars/test.png">
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>
Rank:
</td>
<td style="text-align:right;">
<b>0th</b>
</td>
</tr>
..........
```

And so on for the rest of the lines..

Comment: That's helped a lot, but now when I try to add a second section, they come out as two different rows instead of side by side. What did I do wrong? http://jsfiddle.net/x9Hz9/3/

Comment: you can make a choice: 1) you make a big table with all the different cars inside or 2) you make a different table for each car like in the example here: http://jsfiddle.net/x9Hz9/7/

Comment: the float:left tag will align the tables 1 next to the other. (note that some td and tr tags were missing in your last example.)

Comment: Putting everything in separate tables was what I was looking for, thanks for your help.

Comment: you're welcome. If you want to go a step further note that what Lee Gary said about "hard to maintain" is a good hint, if you're going to make a big site. Writing styling code inside your html is a drawback in the long run.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of putting everything inside a , create 1  for each row and you can put styles on the  tags like this:

```
<tr>
  <td colspan="2">Car 1</td><td colspan="2"> Car 2</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td style="text-align:left">Wins</td>
  <td style="text-align:right">1</td>
  <td style="text-align:left">Wins</td>
  <td style="text-align:right">5</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td style="text-align:left">Poles</td>
  <td style="text-align:right">2</td>
  <td style="text-align:left">Poles</td>
  <td style="text-align:right">12</td>
</tr>
```

it looks ugly and will be hard to maintain, so you can use css:

```
<style>
.left{
  text-align: left;
}
.right{
  text-align: right;
}
</style>
```

Apply the classes

```
<tr>
  <td colspan="2">Car 1</td><td colspan="2"> Car 2</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td class="left">Wins</td>
  <td class="right">1</td>
  <td class="left">Wins</td>
  <td class="right">5</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td class="left">Poles</td>
  <td class="right">2</td>
  <td class="left">Poles</td>
  <td class="right">12</td>
</tr>
```

So that now your styles are easier to maintain, if you ever thought of changing the style. Of course you can do even more precise/optimized [CSS selectors](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cascading_Style_Sheets#Selector), but it might be too much for you, for now

Answer (score 0):

try it

working http://jsfiddle.net/qLrYg/5/

```
<table border="1" cellspacing="0" >
<tr bgcolor="#999999">
    <td width="100"  valign="middle" align="left" >Rank:</td>
    <td width="30"  valign="middle" align="right">0</td>
</tr>
<tr bgcolor="#CCCCCC">
  <td valign="middle" align="left" >Wins:</td>
    <td valign="middle" align="right" >0</td>
</tr>
```